# How to access Cookie set with Passport.js

Tags: node.js, cookies, authentication, passport.js

I'm using Passport.js to achieve login to my Node-App. But in my app, I need to get access to the user's ID and currently, I don't have an idea how to achieve this thing!

How can I access the user-id or should I send it in a cookie myself?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You should introduce the following code in your app, next to the configuration of the strategies:

```
passport.serializeUser(function(user, done) {
   done(null, user.id);
});

passport.deserializeUser(function(obj, done) {
   done(null, obj);
});
```

In this way, when you invoke the `done` function with the authenticated user, passport takes care of storing the userId in a cookie.
Whenever you want to access the userId you can find it in the request body. (in express  `req["user"]`).

You can also develop the `serializeUser` function if you want to store other data in the session. I do it this way:

```
passport.serializeUser(function(user, done) {
   done(null, {
      id: user["id"],
      userName: user["userName"],
      email: user["email"]
   });
});
```

You can find more here: http://passportjs.org/docs/configure

Comment: i have this already i my code - but i need to access the cookie on client side, using javascript - is this possible?

Comment: I'm sorry, I didn't understand that from your question. I just analyzed the cookies in my node.js app and I don't see one set by passportjs. Connect just sets a cookie with the sessionId. The rest of the data is stored on the server. I believe you should manually set a cookie with the desired data and then parse it using javascript on the client. (using express: [link](http://expressjs.com/api.html#res.cookie) ).

Comment: i've solved the problem myself setting a own cookie already but thanks for your info!

Comment: This will set the userid in the session not in the cookie.

Comment: This is very useful

Comment: Does not answer the question and now future readers get confused. Looks like the poster solved by himself.

Answer (score 19):

Add to signin path

```
res.cookie('userid', user.id, { maxAge: 2592000000 });  // Expires in one month
```

Add to signout path

```
res.clearCookie('userid');
```

Comment: I think, the question is how to integrate this with passport as in the passport callbacks and in the strategy, we may not have access to req/res.

Comment: Where should I add this code? I mean from where should I set cookies?

Answer (score 5):

The [answer by user1071182](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15408473/2441655) is correct, but doesn't make clear where to place the cookie-setting code.

Here is a fuller example:

```
app.get("/auth/google/callback",
    passport.authenticate("google"),
    setUserIDResponseCookie,
    (req, res, next)=>{
        // if success
        if (req.user) {
            res.redirect("http://localhost:3000");
        } else {
            res.redirect("http://localhost:3000/login-failed");
        }
        next();
    });

function setUserIDResponseCookie(req, res, next) {
    // if user-id cookie is out of date, update it
    if (req.user?.id != req.cookies["myapp-userid"]) {
        // if user successfully signed in, store user-id in cookie
        if (req.user) {
            res.cookie("myapp-userid", req.user.id, {
                // expire in year 9999 (from: https://stackoverflow.com/a/28289961)
                expires: new Date(253402300000000),
                httpOnly: false, // allows JS code to access it
            });
        } else {
            res.clearCookie("myapp-userid");
        }
    }
    next();
}
```

**Note:** Make sure to:

1. Add the shown handler to the `authXXX/callback` route, not the `authXXX` route.
2. Call `passport.authenticate` "plainly", ie. without the redirect options. If you set the redirect options there, the cookies will not be set properly (from what I remember). Instead, add custom redirect code after the cookies have been set. (as shown above)
3. If you have a "sign out" route, add the handler above to that route as well.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using the `angular-fullstack`generator, this is how I modified `setUserCookie` to get the `_id` in the user cookie (which I later can retrieve in AngularJS).

```
setUserCookie: function(req, res, next) {
    if (req.user) {
        req.user.userInfo['_id'] = req.user._id;
        console.log('Cookie', req.user.userInfo);
        // Splice in _id in cookie
        var userObjWithID = {
            "provider": req.user.userInfo.provider,
            "role": req.user.userInfo.role,
            "name": req.user.userInfo.name,
            "_id": req.user._id
        };
        res.cookie('user', JSON.stringify(userObjWithID));
    }
    next();
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Alternatively you could do the following:

```
passport.serializeUser(User.serializeUser());

passport.deserializeUser(User.deserializeUser());
 app.use((req, res, next) => {
  res.locals.login = req.isAuthenticated();
  res.locals.thisUser = req.user;
  next();
});
```