# nodejs, how to set express session cookie not to expire anytime

Tags: node.js, session

In express, does setting `maxAge=null` in session cookie, sets the session cookie not to expire for life time?

Answer (score 20):

If you don't want the session to expire, set the cookie expires date to a date far in the future:

```
app.use(session({
  store: sessionStore, 
  secret: config.session.secret, 
  cookie: {expires: new Date(253402300000000)}  // Approximately Friday, 31 Dec 9999 23:59:59 GMT
}))
```

[See the express session docs.](https://github.com/expressjs/session#cookiemaxage)

If you're concerned about using a date so far in the future, try `new Date(2147483647000)` (Tue, 19 Jan 2038 03:14:07 GMT, which is `2^31 - 1` in milliseconds)

Comment: Does this work per user that connects? Because it seems you are providing a config to 'app' but this gets only executed once the server starts and not per request, or am I wrong?

Comment: I think you're right that this only gets set once, so the same date will be provided to each user that connects. But since it's so far in the future it's not like you need to update the date instance as time passes.

Comment: fyi: I have found out that if you provide a certain amount of time (3600 ms e.g.), the session will expire at that point in time in the future from the moment on the user starts the session (per user). I guess this is called 'undocumented feature'.

Comment: `new Date(253402300799999)` yields `Fri Dec 31 9999 23:59:59 GMT+0000 (GMT Standard Time)`

Comment: Can we not use `maxAge` for this? I'd think a very large `maxAge` in conjunction with `rolling` should achieve the same result as an `expires` far in the future?

Answer (score 8):

Express is using [Connect's session middleware](http://www.senchalabs.org/connect/session.html) to handle that:

> By default cookie.maxAge is null, meaning no "expires" parameter is
>   set so the cookie becomes a browser-session cookie. When the user
>   closes the browser the cookie (and session) will be removed.