# node.js+passport local authentication

Tags: node.js, express, passport.js

I am developing a web app where after login according to type of user the page should redirect. type of user is defined by user at the time of sign-up. passport local authentication is working fine but what I have to do for redirecting the page according to usertype.. please guide

Comment: Why not make the title something less generic so it's more searchable? Like node.js+passport local authentication: redirect according to user type

Answer (score 0):

If the passport is working you could probably get that information off of the request and then use res.redirect('/whereYouWant'). Post some code? check out this answer for info on looking at the cookie: [How to access Cookie set with Passport.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12258795/how-to-access-cookie-set-with-passport-js)

Answer (score 0):

Why not redirect to a page which takes of any redirections for you? Example:

```
router.get('/login', function(req, res) {
    res.render('login', { user : req.user, status: req.param('status') });
});


router.post('/login', passport.authenticate('local', {
  successRedirect: '/redirect',
  failureRedirect: '/login?status=fail',
}));

router.get('/redirect', function(req, res) {
  if (req.isAuthenticated()) {
      if (req.user.usertype === "admin") {
        res.redirect('/adminpage');
      }

      if (req.user.usertype === "marketing") {
        res.redirect('/marketingpage');
      }

      ......
  }
});
```