# get user_id without rendering any route

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

How do I get logged in user data without making any request to any route (endpoint) ?

```
//how about I want to get logged in user's id here?

router.get('/',function(req,res,next){
  //usually we get data here
}
```

I know we can the user's object using `req.user.id` or store it to `res.locals.userId = req.user.id`

Answer (score 1):

Your server can host zillions of users (it is multi-user).  So, when you're not in a specific request from a specific user, there is no single "current" or "logged in" user.

Only when processing a request are you doing something on behalf of a specific user and thus there is a specific user associated with that request.

Depending upon how your login works, you may have a session store of some kind that has all the currently logged in users in it.  The currently logged in user is typically figured out in a request by looking at a session cookie (for that request) and then looking up that session cookie in a local session store to get the user info from the session store.

---

If the point that you want the user info is in the establishment of a socket.io connection, then you can get access to the cookies at the time the socket.io connection is established via `client.request.headers.cookie`.  Using the cookies, you should be able to get your login session and then get access to any other session info you want (just the same as a normal http request).

```
io.on('connection', function(client) {
    var cookie = client.request.headers.cookie;
    // using the cookie, you should then be able to get to your login session
    // using the session, you should be able to get to any other login data
});
```

A conceptual thing to remember is that the creation of a socket.io connection (which is based on a webSocket) always starts with a normal HTTP request (which is then protocol upgraded to a webSocket connection).  As such, all the normal HTTP things are available at that time (such as cookies, headers, etc...).

If you have not yet implemented any sort of user authentication (that sets the above cookie), then you will need to either have the user authenticate before creating the socket.io connection (so the cookie is there when you access it above) or you will need to implement user authentication as part of the socket.io connection process which is something that is supported via socket.io middleware.

If you're having trouble accessing the cookie from passport, then see this: [How to access Cookie set with Passport.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12258795/how-to-access-cookie-set-with-passport-js).

Comment: this module will help. https://github.com/lmaccherone/node-localstorage but how can I know which user is logged in without doing any request or middleware?

Comment: actually I need user's date without calling any request / middleware is that I init my socket.io outside of any of those request / middleware like this http://pastebin.com/mD48zqs1

Comment: @AliciaBrandon - The `io.on('connection',...)` IS within a user request (you should have mentioned this was where you wanted the info in your question).  This is the start of a socket.io connection.  You can get access to the current connection's cookies at the point the socket was connected via `client.request.headers.cookie`.  From the cookie, you should be able to get access to any logged in info from your session store.

Comment: I got this `cookie: 'io=2OE3YFldQAChuWCwAAAA; connect.sid=s%3A_Hr1XDU31OEOqJ4bPkxkIacjEpk0cnFy.ZyJs608i7K3M%2FpkCUYPfYbp3q%2B6L1CDQoIEWS8dsim8; SQLiteManager_currentLangue=2; __atuvc=38%7C22%2C0%7C23%2C0%7C24%2C0%7C25%2C16%7C26'` How does I relate this with my logged in user?

Comment: @AliciaBrandon - Has your user authenticated and set an auth cookie on the domain and port of your socket.io server?  If not, that has to happen first before there will be any user identifying info in the cookie and is a secure way to know who is making a socket.io connection.  Then, you should be able to see the authentication cookie.  Or, alternatively you could add authentication directly to the socket.io connection process.  Either way you need an authentication process to know who is connecting.

Comment: I'm using passport.js to auth my users. I think socket run before my middleware of passport. Hmm..

Comment: I've tried to put that init of socket within any routes endpoint, but it got multiple triggers once user reload the page. Hmm

Comment: @AliciaBrandon - Please include a lot more of your code so we can see the overall structure of your authentication and event flow.  You're not disclosing enough info for us to help you.  For example, we're 12 hours into trying to help you and only now are you disclosing that you're using passport for user auth.  We need to see all that code.  And, yes socket init code should NEVER go inside a route.

Comment: @AliciaBrandon - The browser loads your web page and passport has its chance to do its thing long before a socket.io connection can be made because the socket.io connection can only be made AFTER the page request is completely done.  So, if your passport code is working properly and the user is successfully logged in on the same port, protocol and domain as the socket.io server, then the cookie will be there for socket.io.  If the cookie is not there, then something is not working properly with your configuraton or with passport or with your design.  We need to see a lot more code.

Comment: I kinda of getting what you're trying to say.. I'm using passport to handle users' session, it should trigger first before socket.io. But I only use session this way `// Passport init
app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());` in app.js

Answer (score 0):

You could use express [middleware](http://expressjs.com/en/guide/using-middleware.html) and check for the user's id before any route is handled, then redirect accordingly.

Comment: It appears to me that the OP is asking about the current user when there is no active request.  Middleware is always part of a request so that wouldn't apply.

Comment: If there is no active request, how could we know about the current user object?  A request of some kind has to be made.